# Problem with Bibliograpy

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am new on Tex studio. I am combining three latex file in one by using \import{File name} command. The problem is that all files are combine normally but they have not shown their references at the end of each paper. Can any one help in this regard ?

Comment: go to `Tools->Command->Biber` anf then run again `pdflatex`

Comment: See also [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). If that does not help, a short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) would be greatly appreciated. From the body of the question we cannot even tell what bibliography system you use.

Comment: \begin{papers}[]
 \import{JESS1501101}
\end{papers}


\begin{papers}[]
 \import{JESS1501102}
\end{papers}

Comment: I use this command....for importing paper....and i follow APA....use only two command in the file....

Comment: \biblography{file}  and \bibliography{style}

Comment: That alone does not even tell us the bibliography package you use, could be more specific? You should then edit the MWE into your question, so it does not get lost in the comments. Plus, syntax highlighting etc is much better in the question than in the comments.

Comment: i m using this command...

\begin{papers}[]
 \import{file1}
\end{papers}

\begin{papers}[]
 \import{file2}
\end{papers}


File 1 and file 2 both are .tex file and have their own list of references in (ref.bib) file which needs to be printed at the end of each file respectively but they are not....

\usepackage{apacite}

Comment: Since you are using `apacite` and not `biblatex`, I will re-tag the question, so people can find it better. Still, please come up with a fully copy-and-paste-able and compilable MWE so we can examine your problem. With the fragments in the comments we can hardly do anything.

Comment: Do you have any update for us, if so, please also provide a MWE, so we can examine what's wrong.